# Getting data from hundreds of fields

Tags: php

This is more of a hypothetical, since I just want to use the most efficient way to go about this.

Say you have a page with over 100 textboxes, and a submit button that bring you to a next page and displays what you've written.

How would I go about only printing the textboxes that have been filled in?

I would know how to do this with a lot of if statements, or a very long switch statement, but perhaps there's a simpler way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, there is.
simply call them numbering them.
for example you'll have textbox1, textbox2, textbox3...
in this way, on the next page you just have to build a for loop.

```
for ($index = 1; $index < 100; $index++) {

    if (!empty($_REQUEST["textbox" . $index]))
    {
        echo "textbox number {$index} isn't empty!";
    }

}
```

in this way you will get each box is full or not.

Comment: Decided to go with this one, though I suspect the other ones work just as well. However, !is_empty doesn't work, and doesn't appear to exist as a function. The !empty function works just fine, though. Works great. Thank you.

Comment: yes, i'm sorry... i meant empty function.
sometimes i confuse it with is_null but this one doesn't have "is" prefix :p
glad it helps you, have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
<?php
    for($i=0; $i<100; $i++){
        if(!empty($_POST['textbox'.$i]))
            echo $_POST['textbox'.$i].'<br>';
    }
?>
```

should work I guess.

*I did not test it*

Answer (score 1):

if the name itself is not important i would give them the name txtbox[]  (name="txtbox[]")
This way you can choose one name for all the boxes that belong together, have a specific array to loop through $_POST['txtbox'] . Then just echo them all

```
foreach($_POST['txtbox'] as $key => $tb) {
  echo "<br>Box " . $key . ": " . $tb;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give them names like `txtbox_1` to `txtbox_100`

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (is_integer(strpos($key, 'txtbox_')) && $value != '') {
        echo "<br />$key = $value ";
    }
}
```